# Application throws an IllegalStateException with LazyColumn, but I have no nested scroll content

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

When navigating from the Settings screen to the Language screen, which contains one LazyColumn of three rows, it throws this exception:

IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed

If anyone can give advice.

```
val listState = rememberLazyListState()
    var selectedIndex by remember{ mutableIntStateOf(-1) }

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(15.dp),
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = MaterialTheme.customColorsPalette.cardContainer
        ),
        elevation = CardDefaults.cardElevation(8.dp)
    ) {
        LazyColumn(state = listState) {
            items(items = list) { language ->
                LanguageRowItem(
                    onClick = {
                        selectedIndex = if (selectedIndex != language.id)
                            language.id else -1
                        tag = language.tag
                        onClickRefreshActivityEnglish()
                    },
                    title = language.title,
                    chosen = language.id == selectedIndex
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

```
@Composable
fun LanguageRowItem(
    onClick: ()-> Unit, title: String, chosen: Boolean
) {
    Card(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        shape = RectangleShape,
        colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(
            containerColor = Color.Transparent
        ),
        onClick = { onClick() }
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(15.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier,
                text = title,
                style = TextStyle(
                    color =
                    if (chosen) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                    else MaterialTheme.customColorsPalette.blackToWhite,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold,
                    fontSize = 18.sp
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added verticleScroll to any root Column modifier? if yes, then that is causing the issue, else please provide all the code snippet.

Comment: @GaneshHulyal
No, I didn't add any verticalScroll, and nothing related to this code but this one in the Settings screen: navController.navigate(Screen.Language.route) and the NavGraph call in activity, and I don't  think this will cause that exception.